# Protractor locator

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I have some problem to locate an element.

```
<li ng-if="user" ng-cloak ng-click="logout()"><a style="font-size: 16px;  cursor: pointer;">
                <span class="fa fa-power-off"></span>&nbsp;Logout</a></li>
```

I have logout element and trying to click on it but nothing works.]
I tried:
1.

```
var logout =  element(by.cssContainingText('li[ng-click*=logout()]'));
```

2.

```
 var logout =  element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-scope','Logout'));
```

3.

```
 var logout =  element(by.cssContainingText('.fa ','Logout'));
```

Comment: This looks like a menu item of a menu. Have you tried to expand the menu by, I'm guessing, clicking the parent `ul` element first? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var logout = element( by.css('[ng-click="logout()"]') ).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var logout =  element(by.linkText('Logout'));
```

Comment: var logout =  element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-scope','Logout'));    that somehow work but cannot click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the anchor tag rather than on the list element. Try below example -

```
var logout =  element(by.css('li[ng-if="user"] a'));
logout.click();
```

Hope this helps.